# Angular Material options - Hardcoded value working, dynamically returned value not

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want a mat-option filter to select all options in default. For that I have used

```js
.setValue([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

But now I need the array to be passed dynamically from api service.

So I did this:

```js
this.listApiService.getListOfEventTypes().subscribe(data => {
      (data as Array<any>).forEach(type => {
        this.allSelectedEventTypes.push(type.Id);
      });
    });

.setValue(this.allSelectedEventTypes);
```

Even this returning the same array, but not in expected way the filter is selecting the default options.

Here are the output I got when I tried to print in console.

Hardcoded array:

```js
Array(8) [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
```

Dynamically returned array:

```js
Array []
```

and when I expand this:

```js
[]
0: 1
​1: 2
​2: 3
3: 4
​4: 5
​5: 6
​6: 7
​7: 8
​length: 8
```

But this is not working with selecting all default multiple selections in mat option filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the `.setValue` function inside the subscription.

```
this.listApiService.getListOfEventTypes().subscribe(data => {
  (data as Array<any>).forEach(type => {
    this.allSelectedEventTypes.push(type.Id);
  });
  this.yourVariable.setValue(this.allSelectedEventTypes);  //<-----
});
```

In general it takes some time for an API to return the result, so most of the times the function that contains the call will be run completely.

If you place your `setValue` in the function as you did it will be run before the result arrives.